# Writing an R function, which only subsets when stated

Tags: r, function, arguments, subset, option-type

I am trying to write a function that pulls out means, and min and max from a data frame for a specific column (depth), and it can be classed by two categorical variables, so in the function one is grouped by type variable. The other categorical variable is that the data got collected either in 2020 or 2021. I want the default function to pull out data for all years, unless stated in the argument and then subset the data by year. It would also be nice if I could change the variable (eg length instead of depth).
Here is my code

```
analysis <- function(data=measurements, yearX=2020){
  data %>%
    subset(year == yearX) %>%  ## Subsets the dataset by specific year
    group_by(type) %>%  ## groups the data by type 
    summarise(mBD=mean(depth), sdBD=sd(depth), minBD=min(depth),
              maxBD=max(depth), median=median(depth), 
              range=(max(depth) - min(depth)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result may look like so:

```r
set.seed(123)

measurements <- data.frame(
  year = rep(2020:2021, each = 10),
  type = rep(c("A", "B")),
  length = runif(20),
  depth = runif(20)
)

library(dplyr)

analysis <- function(data = measurements, x, yearX = NULL) {
  # Subset by year if given
  if (!is.null(yearX)) data <- filter(data, year %in% yearX) 
  data %>%
    group_by(type) %>%
    summarise(across({{x}}, .fns = list(
      mBD = mean, 
      sdBD = sd, 
      minBD = min, 
      maxBD = max, 
      median = median, 
      range = ~ diff(range(.x))), .names = "{.fn}"
      ))
}

analysis(x = depth)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 7
#>   type    mBD  sdBD  minBD maxBD median range
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A     0.577 0.290 0.0246 0.963  0.648 0.938
#> 2 B     0.576 0.299 0.147  0.994  0.643 0.847

analysis(measurements, depth, 2020)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 7
#>   type    mBD  sdBD minBD maxBD median range
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A     0.604 0.217 0.289 0.890  0.641 0.600
#> 2 B     0.627 0.307 0.147 0.994  0.693 0.847

analysis(measurements, length, 2021)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 7
#>   type    mBD  sdBD  minBD maxBD median range
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A     0.462 0.348 0.103  0.957  0.328 0.854
#> 2 B     0.584 0.370 0.0421 0.955  0.573 0.912
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this function works exactly as I expected. just one quick question, what do the .fn bits mean? (like the .fns = list and .names = "{.fn}"?

Comment: Hi John. You are welcome. Using `dplyr::across` you could pass a (named) list of functions via `.fns` which will then be applied to the column `x` passed to the function. It's a bit more concise as we don't have to repeat the argument for each function. Using the `.names` argument you could specify how the columns in the aggregated dataset should be named. "{.fn}" is `glue` notation and means to label each column by the name given to function when using `.fns`.

Answer (score 0):

To benefit from the convenience of `subset()` in the function, we could use `match.call()` and `match` it with the `formalArgs` of `subset.default` to create a `subset` call which we may `eval`uate. If no subset is specified, the lines are like omitted.

For the remainder we define a summarize function, where we should define what happens when there are `NA's`, and use it in `aggregate()` with a formula easily created with `reformulate()`.

With a case handling we could also omit the grouping.

```
FUN <- function(..., col, group=NA, na.rm=FALSE) {
  cll <- match.call()
  m <- match(formalArgs(subset.default), names(cll), 0L)
  m <- cll[c(1L, m)]
  m[[1L]] <- quote(subset)
  dat <- eval(m)
  mysum <- function(x) c(mBD=mean(x, na.rm=na.rm), sdBD=sd(x, na.rm=na.rm), 
                         minBD=min(x, na.rm=na.rm), maxBD=max(x, na.rm=na.rm), 
                         median=median(x, na.rm=na.rm), 
                         range=max(x, na.rm=na.rm) - min(x, na.rm=na.rm))
  if (!is.na(group)) {
    res <- aggregate(reformulate(group, col), dat, mysum)
  } else {
    res <- mysum(dat[, col])
  }
  return(res)
}
```

### Usage

```
FUN(x=measurements, col='depth', group='type')
#   type  depth.mBD depth.sdBD depth.minBD depth.maxBD depth.median depth.range
# 1    A 0.57739614 0.29037002  0.02461368  0.96302423   0.64810631  0.93841055
# 2    B 0.57604555 0.29862847  0.14711365  0.99426978   0.64347271  0.84715613

FUN(x=measurements, col='depth', group='type', subset=year == 2020)
#   type depth.mBD depth.sdBD depth.minBD depth.maxBD depth.median depth.range
# 1    A 0.6037955  0.2169419   0.2891597   0.8895393    0.6405068   0.6003796
# 2    B 0.6273719  0.3070970   0.1471136   0.9942698    0.6928034   0.8471561

FUN(x=measurements, col='length', group='type', subset=year == 2020)
#   type length.mBD length.sdBD length.minBD length.maxBD length.median length.range
# 1    A  0.5433124   0.2457008    0.2875775    0.9404673     0.5281055    0.6528898
# 2    B  0.6131826   0.3633747    0.0455565    0.8924190     0.7883051    0.8468625

FUN(x=measurements, col='depth', group=NA)
#        mBD       sdBD      minBD      maxBD     median      range 
# 0.57672085 0.28667353 0.02461368 0.99426978 0.64810631 0.96965609
```

---

*Data (borrowed from stefan):*

```
measurements <- structure(list(year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L), type = c("A", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "B"), length = c(0.287577520124614, 0.788305135443807, 
0.4089769218117, 0.883017404004931, 0.940467284293845, 0.0455564993899316, 
0.528105488047004, 0.892419044394046, 0.551435014465824, 0.456614735303447, 
0.956833345349878, 0.453334156190977, 0.677570635452867, 0.572633401956409, 
0.102924682665616, 0.899824970401824, 0.24608773435466, 0.0420595335308462, 
0.327920719282702, 0.954503649147227), depth = c(0.889539316063747, 
0.6928034061566, 0.640506813768297, 0.994269776623696, 0.655705799115822, 
0.708530468167737, 0.544066024711356, 0.59414202044718, 0.28915973729454, 
0.147113647311926, 0.963024232536554, 0.902299045119435, 0.690705278422683, 
0.795467417687178, 0.0246136845089495, 0.477795971091837, 0.758459537522867, 
0.216407935833558, 0.318181007634848, 0.231625785352662)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```